# Stoplights showing script instead of colors

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, 2019, js

Here is the original post about the Stoplights for SP 2016 on prem.

[Stoplight Indicators Pulling From Multiple Columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252477/stoplight-indicators-pulling-from-multiple-columns)

This is the script I have on the page that rendered the Stoplight

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
 var overrideNameField = {};
 overrideNameField.Templates = {};
 // This action will edit the "Indicator" field. You can change the "Status" to another column.
 overrideNameField.Templates.Fields = {
 "Status Indicator": { "View": overrideNameFieldTemplate }
  };

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideNameField);

 })();
function overrideNameFieldTemplate(ctx) {
 //get the column value.
var currentVal= ctx.CurrentItem["Status Indicator"];
// Render the column
return "<div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:50px; color:"+currentVal+";'>•</div>";
}
  </script>
```

It has worked perfectly for the last two years. We are still in classic view. If there are any pointers out there on how to update that script to work with 2019 on prem that would be wonderful.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you import this JavaScript file. Use JSLink to make this script to work

Comment: It was placed directly under the list and worked for over 2 years wonderfully.  After the migration, I tried using JSLink and that too did not work.

Comment: @ChrisL I have tested the original script in SharePoint Server 2019, and it is working just fine. 
Make sure you use the **internal name** instead of the current display name of the column in the script. Delete the Script Editor web part from page and then add the script again.

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT I did all that and still nothing.  The MDS is not active, either.

Comment: @ChrisL Not sure what the problem is, but maybe try using the script in a new created list and see if it works. Might have something to do with the migration process.